# enforce empty JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, schema-design

I want a JSON schema that enforces an empty JSON object, e.g. `{}`

Is this a good idea and possible?

I tried the following but it allows me to enter anything in the JSON body:

```
{
   "description": "voice mail record",
   "type": "object",
   "additionalProperties": false,
   "properties": {
    }
 }
```

Comment: how about enforcing the opposite? I mean [non-emptiness of object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651589/enforce-object-non-emptyness-using-json-schema)?

Comment: @Mahesha999 swap `additionalProperties: false` for `minProperties: 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer yes this should enforce an empty schema - the validator I was using had a bug

http://groups.google.co.uk/group/json-schema/browse_thread/thread/d0017b3985c8542b/106ce4afc1763eeb?hl=en&q=empty+schema+ollie&safe=on